# Change json object with jq

Tags: json, jq

how can I update servers object in my json using jq?

```
"tags": [],
  "servers": [],
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "cookie": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "cookie",
        "name": "store",
        "description": "Store API"
      }
    },
```

I need to have servers like that:

```
      "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:5000",
      "description": "Localhost server"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '{"tags": [],
  "servers": [],
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "cookie": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "in": "cookie",
        "name": "store",
        "description": "Store API"
      }
    }
}}' | jq '.servers = [{url:"http://localhost:5000", description: "Localhost server"}]'
```

Or, for a fixed json file (adding missing `}`):

```
jq '.servers = [{url:"http://localhost:5000", description: "Localhost server"}]' file.json
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to save this updated json then?

Comment: I need to use it in pipeline and it's not yml valid

Comment: I don't understand. I used the `echo` because it shows the fixed input (missing `}`). The output is a valid json - but you suddenly mention yaml. Please provide more details.

Comment: I have json file with more data like in this example above. So I need to cat this whole json file and use somehow jq for update servers in that json file and save this updated version. I'll use this script in "before_script" in gitlab-ci.yml file and this jq command above is not yml valid, I dunno why.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question about including the command to a yml file?